# Nginx on macOS : open files resource limit

Tags: macos, nginx

I'm having configuration errors and I have researched online but I'm not quite sure what the problem is.  I'm wanting to install PHP and Nginx on a os x 10.7.5 operating system.  Whenever i try to start or stop the server I get the following errors:

```
tone$ nginx
nginx: [warn] 1024 worker_connections exceed open file resource limit: 256
alcfwl128:~ tolbert$ nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.3/logs/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)

nginx -s stop
nginx: [error] open() "/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.3/logs/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

For the first error I have tried the following command: `tone$ ulimit -n 65536`

But I get this error: `-bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument`
I'm not sure if I'm to create the logs folder in the directory along with the nginx.pid file or if it is located somewhere else. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Try this? http://charles.lescampeurs.org/2009/03/09/nginx-and-worker_connections-are-more-than-open-file-resource-limit-warning

Comment: I came across this article but it was not clear to me as to where to add the command "ulimit -n 65536"

Comment: I'm not much of a pro on nginx either ;) Try this link from the comments: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/150953

Comment: I looked at that page as well and it really offers no resolution.  From my research I believe you have to edit the launchd.conf file in the etc directory.  I don't see that file and based on these instructions http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/tuning/open-files-limit/ it says to create or edit than reboot.  I followed those directions but when I run the launchctl limit command I get the same results.  I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Gah! Lame. Wish I knew more about nginx to assist.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try this in your terminal:

```
ulimit -a
```

And the result should be sth similar to this:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

In your case, to increase the open files limit to 1024, use this code:

```
ulimit -n 1024
```

Check by running `sudo nginx -t` and let's hope you don't see the error again

Comment: Small typo on your answer there: it's `ulimit -a`, not `ulimit-a`

Answer (score 13):

Add to `nginx.conf` in main section:

```
worker_rlimit_nofile 1024;
```

Comment: I prefer this answer. Much less intrusive.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with [lifecomm's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5603104/lifecom) solution, better targeting of specific nginx issue:

*worker_rlimit_nofile changes the limit on the maximum number of open files (RLIMIT_NOFILE) for worker processes. Used to increase the limit without restarting the main process.*